# Hypotheses for likelihood-ratio confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I'm working on a physics research project, and in the process I've managed to both firm up my understanding of statistical significance (I hope) and confuse myself somewhat.  The question I'm looking at involves likelihood-ratio testing of nested models.  I'll describe my understanding of the likelihood-ratio test first (feel free to correct any misconceptions here);  and then I'll ask my question.

#### My understanding:

Suppose we have a set of $N$ observations $x_i = \{x_1, \dots, x_N \}$, and we know the likelihood of this set of measurements via some probability distribution $\mathcal{P}(x_i; \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ which depends on a set of continuous parameters $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$.  We wish to test the following two hypotheses:

- $H_0$:  $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = 0$.
- $H_1$:  at least one of the parameters is non-zero.

The standard likelihood-ratio test involves first maximizing the overall likelihood over all values of $\alpha$.  If $\mathcal{P}$ is maximized when $\vec{\alpha} = \vec{\alpha}_{max} \equiv (\alpha_{1max}, \alpha_{2max}, \alpha_{3max})$, then we construct the quantity
$$
\lambda = 2 \left[ \ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, \alpha_{1max}, \alpha_{2max}, \alpha_{3max}) - \ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, 0,0,0) \right].
$$
According to Wilks' theorem, this quantity will be asymptotically distributed according to a $\chi^2$ distribution with three degrees of freedom, and we can use this fact to construct a statistical significance criterion.  For example, if we want to only have a $\beta = 5\%$ chance of a Type I error in rejecting $H_0$, we would reject $H_0$ if $\lambda$ exceeded about 7.81, since that corresponds to the 95% quantile in the $\chi^2_3$ distribution.

#### The question:

So far so good.  But it also seems like this process is then adapted to look at confidence intervals of the parameters, and this is where I get lost.  Specifically, let's suppose that we want to place a confidence interval for $\alpha_1$.  From what I've found online, it looks common to construct a confidence interval for $\alpha_1$ in one of two ways:

- Find the values of $\alpha_1$ for which the quantity $$2 \left[ \ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, \alpha_{1max}, \alpha_{2max}, \alpha_{3max}) - \ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2max}, \alpha_{3max})\right] $$ falls below the $(1-\beta)$ quantile in the $\chi_1^2$ distribution, for whatever value of $\beta$ you prefer.
- Find the values of $\alpha_1$ for which the quantity $$\max_{\alpha_2, \alpha_3} \left\{ 2 \left[\ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, \alpha_{1max}, \alpha_{2max}, \alpha_{3max}) - \ln \mathcal{P}(x_i, \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \alpha_{3})\right]\right\}$$ falls below the $(1-\beta)$ quantile in the $\chi_1^2$ distribution, for whatever value of $\beta$ you prefer.  (I believe this is called a "profile confidence interval"?)

This looks similar enough to the likelihood-ratio test that it seems like we should be able to phrase it in terms of hypotheses in the same way;  but I haven't been able to figure out how.  **Can these latter two tests be phrased in terms of a null hypothesis and an alternate hypothesis, in the same way the likelihood-ratio test can?**  Or is a null hypothesis and an alternate hypothesis the wrong way to think about these confidence intervals?